# im not able to pass an array to controller using jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

my java script is like below....

```
    var selected_classification = [];
    $.each($("input[name='classi_check']:checked"), function () {
        selected_classification.push($(this).closest("tr").find('.classi_name').text());
    });
                 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: sbomsearch.exportsbom,
            
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data:{ modelcode : selected_classification },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != '') {

                    alert("data success");}
               




            }
        });
```

my controller method is ..

```
      public JsonResult exportsbom( string[] modelcode)
      {
         string x = modelcode[0];
         return json("");
          }
```

i get an error when i try to assign an element of an array to a string...
Please help........

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Is that error on backend or frontend side? Does that error have some message?

Comment: Since you are passing an array, You have do like this `data: { 'modelcode' : JSON.stringify(selected_classification) },`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. You need to stringify your array in the Javascript first

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: sbomsearch.exportsbom,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { modelcode : JSON.stringify(selected_classification) },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != '') {
                alert("data success");
            }
        }
    });
```